# json array search in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am dealing with a json array and performing search on it. The code seems to be ok but not giving the output. This is my code

```
var restaurants = [
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "McDonald's", "food" : "burger",      "drink" : "coke", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "KFC", "food" : "chicken", "drink" : "pepsi", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Pizza Hut",  "food" : "pizza", "drink" : "sprite", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Dominos",  "food" : "pizza", "drink" : "root beer", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Popeyes",  "food" : "chicken", "drink" : "mist", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }}
      ];
```

And my method for search is

```
function filter( restaurants, food, drink) { 

var result = [];

for( var i= 0, len = restaurants.length; i < len; i++) {
    var el = restaurants.restaurant[i];

    if( el.food === food && el.drink === drink ) {
        result.push( el );
    }
}

return result;
}
```

But in console it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. What is wrong with the function? How can i perform  a complete search? Is it about string length function?

Comment: How is your `filter` function being called? My guess is that your `restaurants` parameter is overriding the global `restaurants` that contains the actual data.

Comment: <input name="search" type="text" maxlength="512" id="search" class="searchField" autocomplete="off" title="" />
 <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="filter()" id="btnSearch" class="buttonSearch" />

Comment: You must pass the `restaurants` variable in `filter()` function or it throws an error.

Comment: You want to search by `food` and `drink`, yet, you're only defining single `<input>` element to enter data to search for. However, the main problem is that you're not passing the arguments to the `filter` function you declared.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in this line

```
var el = restaurants.restaurant[i];
```

It has to be

```
var el = restaurants[i].restaurant;
```

[JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/dilesizotu/edit?html,js,console,output)

I recommend your to use lodash to handle arrays. It will make your code simpler. [JsBin Example with lodash](http://jsbin.com/bojahucosa/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: `restaurants.restaurant` is actually nothing as `restaurants` is an array that has no key `restaurant`. `restaurants[i]` is the `i`th element of the array, that contains an object that has the key `restaurant`.

Comment: Why do you recommend iodash to handle arrays? It would be better to learn how to deal with objects and arrays in the ECMA Script Standard before someone uses high level tools that hide any internals from the programmer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Comment: ikrabbe, thanks I missed "[i]". I think it's good to know about such libraries as lodash and use them in projects in order not to reinvent the wheel

Comment: knowing about how a wheel is attached to your vehicle and how to replace it can save your live. The iodash `_.find` method returns an object, which is different from what you get from OP's `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = restaurants.restaurant[i];
```

You choose element [i] of restaurants.restaurant which is undefined because `restaurants` is your array and `restaurant` is the object that is contained in all array elements.

Use

```
var el = restaurants[i].restaurant;
```

With this it shows

```
JSON.stringify(filter(restaurants,"burger","coke"))
"[{"name":"McDonald's","food":"burger","drink":"coke","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}]"    filter(restaurants, "burger","coke")
```

Answer (score 0):

`restaurants` is an array and you have to access the element of it with `index` not with property. Working code:

```
var restaurants = [
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "McDonald's", "food" : "burger",      "drink" : "coke", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "KFC", "food" : "chicken", "drink" : "pepsi", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Pizza Hut",  "food" : "pizza", "drink" : "sprite", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Dominos",  "food" : "pizza", "drink" : "root beer", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }},
        {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Popeyes",  "food" : "chicken", "drink" : "mist", "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }}
      ];

function filter( restaurants, food, drink) { 
    var result = [];
    for( var i= 0, len = restaurants.length; i < len; i++) {
        var el = restaurants[i].restaurant; // changed here from - var el = restaurants.restaurant[i];
        if( el.food === food && el.drink === drink ) {
            result.push( el );
        }
    }
    return result;
    }

filter(restaurants,"burger","coke");
```